# Cannot import cfnresponse AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm facing the issue with error while executing aws lambda function which is 'Unable to import module 'custom_resource_lambda': No module named cfnresponse'. I saw the one case but solution was to change runtime python version to 2.7, but it does not work for me. Please give me know what I am doing wrong. Cheers

```
import json
import boto3
import cfnresponse
from common_helpers.constants_v2 import LOGGER_NAME
import os
import logging



DEBUG_MODE = os.getenv('DEBUG_MODE', 'false')
ENV_NAME = os.getenv('COMPUTE_ENVIRONMENT_NAME')

batch_client = boto3.client('batch')

# Configure logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
if DEBUG_MODE == 'true':
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info("Received event: " + json.dumps(event))
    try:
        if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
            send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS)
            return
        response = batch_client.describe_compute_environments(
            computeEnvironments=[
                ENV_NAME,
            ],
        )
        compute_env_details = response.get('computeEnvironments')
        cluster_arn = compute_env_details[0]['ecsClusterArn']
        cluster_name = cluster_arn.split('/')[1]
        data = dict(Data=dict(
            ClusterArn=cluster_arn,
            ClusterName=cluster_name))
        event.update(data)
        cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS)
    except BaseException as e:
        send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the library in the root of your lambda (regardless of python version)

For that you need to run this command in the root of your lambda function

```
pip install cfnresponse -t .
```

When the installation finish, zip your lambda and upload again. And the error should go away.